# Contiguous Memory Allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management

In an application i have to allocate two buffers of 480 MB each. Memory allocation is done using HeapAlloc method. The application works fine in the systems where not many applications are running.  But in system where other applications are also running memory is not allocated because of non availability of contiguous memory. Even though the memory space(non contiguous) is available but it is not allocated.

Need help to allocate two buffers of 480 MB even if non contiguous memory is available.

Comment: You can't. Add more memory (swap or RAM), or use non-contiguous containers such as [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque).

Comment: Can you achieve a similar result by using 2 memory mapped files?  At that point, the system manages the memory but you see a flat, contiguous hunk IIRC.

Comment: @JimR: That's really not very different from what you get from a normal allocation function, except that with a normal allocation function the system memory-maps the pagefile and also knows you'd prefer to avoid actually writing the changes to disk.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The advantage I was thinking of was that the system manages the memory problem for you.  It might be worth trying...

Answer (score 3):

The situation you describe is not possible in a full featured OS which gives each process its own address space.  It doesn't matter how many other applications are running, they won't affect contiguity of the free address space in your process.  And virtual memory can map discontiguous physical memory addresses to a contiguous range in virtual address space.

Only in an embedded system without a memory management unit could the existence of other tasks cause your program to suffer memory fragmentation.

`HeapAlloc()` suggests Windows, which does give a separate address space to each process.  The most likely explanation there is that your private address space is fragmented by libraries (DLLs) loading in scattered locations.  You can rebase the libraries you use to avoid this and provide larger contiguous blocks of address space.

Comment: User space vs kernel space vs physical memory. On my list of things every programmer should know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `fAllocation` specified as `MEM_LARGE_PAGES`.  This enables [large page support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), note that you must check [GetLargePageMinimum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to ensure that the system supports lage pages.

Also note that this is likely to be slow as this page [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Large-page memory regions may be difficult to obtain after the system has been running for a long time because the physical space for each large page must be contiguous, but the memory may have become fragmented. Allocating large pages under these conditions can significantly affect system performance. Therefore, applications should avoid making repeated large-page allocations and instead allocate all large pages one time, at startup.

Comment: The size of individual pages isn't going to have much effect on this.  Large pages are desirable when doing random access in large arrays because each entry in the page table corresponds to a greater fraction of the data, so fewer entries are needed and are more likely to all fit in the Translation Look-aside Buffer (which acts as a cache for the page table).

Answer (score 0):

Use VirtualAlloc. The underlying memory that backs the virtual pages need not be contiguous and you will always have your full virtual address space (2GB on a 32 bit system, I think 8 or 16 TB on Windows x64, I can't remember.) HeapAlloc can become fragmented (through your process's use, not others.) Your address space can also become fragmented, so try allocating it early in your application. I actually don't recommend HeapAlloc for anything, you can just use new and delete (which call malloc and free) For large blocks like yours malloc will call VirtualAlloc on Windows.

Comment: `HeapAlloc` will also call `VirtualAlloc`

Comment: I didn't know that, sounds like the problem is address space fragmentation then. Possibly caused by loaded libraries, as you say.

Comment: Well, apparently it's an option when the heap is created.  "If dwMaximumSize is 0, the heap can grow in size. The heap's size is limited only by the available memory. Requests to allocate memory blocks larger than the limit for a fixed-size heap do not automatically fail; instead, the system calls the VirtualAlloc function to obtain the memory that is needed for large blocks. Applications that need to allocate large memory blocks should set dwMaximumSize to 0."